# Finding an orthonormal matrix with 2 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

You are given two $3D$ unit vector $\hat{v}, \hat{w}$

Find a $3 \times 3$ Orthonormal matrix $A$ such that

$$A\hat{v} = \hat{w}$$
$$\mathrm{and}$$
$$det(A) = 1$$

My incomplete solution

$$A\hat{v} = \hat{w}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\v_z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}w_x\\w_y\\w_z\end{bmatrix}$$

$$w_x = v_x a_{11} + v_y a_{12} + v_z a_{13}$$
$$w_y = v_x a_{21} + v_y a_{22} + v_z a_{23}$$
$$w_z = v_x a_{31} + v_y a_{32} + v_z a_{33}$$

As its an orthonormal matrix, which means the dot product of any 2 vector before and after the transformation is same, we could leverage this fact and so...

$$v_x = \begin{bmatrix}w_x\\w_y\\w_z\end{bmatrix}\cdot{}\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\a_{31}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_y = \begin{bmatrix}w_x\\w_y\\w_z\end{bmatrix}\cdot{}\begin{bmatrix}a_{12}\\a_{22}\\a_{32}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_z = \begin{bmatrix}w_x\\w_y\\w_z\end{bmatrix}\cdot{}\begin{bmatrix}a_{13}\\a_{23}\\a_{33}\end{bmatrix}$$

When expanded...

$$v_x = w_x a_{11} + w_y a_{21} + w_z a_{31}$$
$$v_y = w_x a_{12} + w_y a_{22} + w_z a_{32}$$
$$v_z = w_x a_{13} + w_y a_{23} + w_z a_{33}$$

But there are 9 unknowns and these are only 6 equation i dont know what to do now.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I tried creating a system of equation but falling short of 3 equation as there are 9 unknowns

Comment: then show what have you done

Comment: Welcome to [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) Kushagra Actually, It is expected to show the efforts you did to solve the problem.
So, please try to show your efforts.

Comment: I am adding my attempt at solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about $A$ having positive determinant you can perform a reflection along the bisector line between $v$ and $w$. Consider $\xi = \frac{v+w}{2}$. Then consider the projection matrix onto the line spanned by $\xi$. This is $P_\xi = \xi\cdot \xi^t$. You can check that the matrix $A=-\text{Id}+2P_\xi$ is an orthogonal matrix sending $w$ to $v$ (and viceversa).